# If I want to have a list of all distinct Categories and Ratings, should I do it on my own?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I admit that I'm new to the Azure Search service and I've performed my first tests today on querying an index.
I've got a question regarding the Filters, suppose this scenario.

I've got a Product with properties

```
public class SearchableProduct
{
   int Id {get;set;}
   string Title {get;set;}
   string Category {get;set;}
   int Rating {get;set;}
}
```

Now If I want to have a list of all distinct Categories and Ratings should I do it on my own having a distinct one on the SQL View that's bound to the index or can I just ask to the SearchService retrieve all the distinct categories? and if so, how?

I've created a SQL view with the products that join different tables and on my main DB I've also the Category table, so I just need to understand the best practice

Answer (score 1):

You can do a facet search to get the distinct values of a property.

```cs
var options = new SearchOptions()
{
    Filter = filter,
    Size = 0,
};
foreach (var facet in facets) //where facets are the property names
{
    options.Facets.Add(facet);
}
var response = await Client.SearchAsync<SearchDocument>(search, options);
var facets = response.Value.Facets;
```

For it to work the properties you use should be enabled as facetable properties. If you create the index using the C# SDK you use attributes to apply that setting:

```cs
[SimpleField(IsFacetable = true)]
public string Example { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use a facet is the correct one for your question. Assuming that your number of unique categories and ratings can be supported by a refiner.

I have a complicated data model where I maintain "unique values" for a large selection of properties. This helps us get an overview of what 3000+ families do we have, or categories, groups, sub-groups, sub-families and a long list of others.